# Passing current object while setting parameters in object initializer in linq

Tags: linq

```
  var userData = (from u in DB.user_data
                                     join p in DB.users on u.userid equals p.userid
                                     join s in DB.roles on p.roleid equals s.roleid
                                     where u.deptid == 24
                                     select new UserData()
                                     {
                                         userId = u.id,
                                         RoleName = s.Name,
                                         CreateDate = u.Create_date,
                                         Active = u.Active,
                                         ValidTokens = GetTokencount(-- userdata  --) -- how to pass current userdata object here

                                     }).ToList();
```

following is the global method from which I get the available taken counts for a user based on a logic

```
public int GetTokencount(UserData objUserData)
{

// code to get count goes here 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. When you're in the object initializer, the current `UserData` object hasn't been initialized yet, so you cannot reference it.

Instead, you can loop through the collection after it's been created to set your `ValidTokens` property on each `UserData` instance.